# Cannot suppress debug logging of framework classes with spring boot and logback

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I am working on a spring boot microservice application that uses logback for logging.

The standard logback.xml is in the default place (main/resources) and is obviously used as I can add logger-statements and they are effective.

Its content looks like this (standard apart from removed comments and the two additional logger directives):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/> 

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="my.app.package.MyClass" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

However, even though I put this into the logback.xml file:

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
```

I get tons of debug log output from framework classes like this here:

```
2015-09-16 10:49:40.733 DEBUG 96549 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'contextAttributes': no URL paths identified
```

What is wrong with my setup? Why are framework classes not respecting my logback config?

Comment: Are you by any change starting the application with `--debug` or `--trace`? Instead of adding a `logback.xml` try adding `logging.level.org.springframework=INFO` and `logging.level.my.app.package.MyClass=DEBUG` to `application.properties`. For setting only levels you don't need a custom `logback.xml`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything. I just tried with using -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=INFO. 

Besides, I would like to use a custom logback.xml because I find it more convenient to handle in my current setup than changing application or system properties. Looks like the problem is something different, however.

Comment: There's two things that you can do to clarify the correct configuration is being read.  One is to print it out in the program using the `StatusPrinter` the other is to turn on debug in the file using `<configuration debug="true"> ` at the top of your logback.xml. See: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html. Once you are sure it's the correct config you can determine that the settings are correct, one way is to construct loggers yourself and check their levels.

Comment: What is the "standard logback.xml" you mention? Have you shown the whole configuration file? If your root logger has level DEBUG, all of the org.springframework events will be logged to DEBUG via that because you have not specified 'additivity = false' for your "org.springframework"-logger.

Comment: My bad. There's a simple explanation, i.e. there was a logging-related line in application.properties slipped in by accident by another developer. this takes precedence over the logback.xml. Everything works as it should, so sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Can you tell me which line was that, cause I have same issue right now and it's really frustrating me?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but it was something along the lines of https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html (the example for application.properties)